# Why is the Upload checkbox for GP Services missing when publishing to ArcGIS Server on Amazon EC2?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.4, geoprocessing-service, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to publish my own GP services to a GIS server instance with ArcGIS Server 10.4.1 built on Amazon EC2. In the service editor window, I do not see the "Upload" checkbock that typically shows when publishing GP services on a server. The WPS checkbox is ALSO missing.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Is this normal?

I want the users of my web app to be able to upload files to use my GP services like I always did for on premise servers.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unaware if the Server deployed to Amazon would have different available settings. I'd expect these options should be available.

Try the following at your own risk (as it involves modifying files you shouldnt be touching)

Open the following in a text editor: `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\bin\ServerTypes.dat`

Find the heading that starts with:

```
<ServerObjectType>
        <Name>GPServer</Name>
```

Before the terminating `</ServerObjectType>` tag for this section, you should have the following which ensures you can upload and enable WPS while publishing.

```
<Info>
    <DefaultWebCapabilities></DefaultWebCapabilities>
    <AllWebCapabilities>Uploads</AllWebCapabilities>
</Info>
<ExtensionTypes>
    <ExtensionType>
        <Name>WPSServer</Name>
        <DisplayName>WPS</DisplayName>
        <PROGID>esriGeoprocessing.WPSServer</PROGID>
        <Description>WPS Server Object Extension</Description>
    </ExtensionType>            
</ExtensionTypes>
```

Note - this file also exists on the server, but I'm pretty sure its the arcmap version you need to modify.

Comment: thanks so much! I will try these options and let you know what happens...I would think that the settings should not be different either, hence why I was surprised!